# Compacité et espace métrique

Tags: general-topology, analysis

i have this exercise:

> "Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B\subset E$ are nonempty such
>   that $A$ is compact and $B$ closed,and $A\cap B= \emptyset$ prove that
>   $d(A,B)>0$"

I need a solution without using the continuity of $d(.,B)$ on the compact $A$.

For example if i suppose by contradiction that $d(A,B)=0$ i can say that there exists two sequences $(a_n), (b_n)$ sunch that $d(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow 0$ and since $A$ is compact so $(a_n) $ has a convergent sub-sequence. but how to continu ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $a_{n_k}$ your convergent sub-sequence to $a\in A$. We have:
$$d(b_{n_k},a)\leq d(b_{n_k},a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},a)$$

Comment: so $(b_{n_k})$ converge to a and as $(b_{n_k})\in B$ and $B$ is closed then $a \in B$ contradiction with the fact that $A\cap B=\emptyset$ but how to introdious $b_{n_k}$ ?

Comment: You have said that there exists a convergent sub-sequence of $a_n$, call it $a_{n_k}$ for a strictly increasing sequence of integers, and you get $b_{n_k}$.

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: On a deux suite $a_n$ et $b_n$. On sait que l'on peut trouver une sous-suite $a_{n_k}$ de $a_n$ qui converge vers $a$. On montre (et vous l'avez fait) que la sous-suite $b_{n_k}$ de $b_n$ converge aussi vers $a$, où est le problème ?

Comment: pourquoi on introduit $b_{n_k}$ on laisse la suite $b_n$ pourquoi travailler avec une sous suite ?

Comment: On sait que $d(a_{n_k},a)$ tend vers $0$. Comme $a_{n_k}$ est "proche " de $b_{n_k}$, on essaie (et on réussit) de montrer que $d(b_{n_k}, a)$ converge aussi vers $0$. Mais on ne sait pas si $d(b_n,a)$ converge vers $0$ ou non.

Comment: comment introduire $b_{n_k}$ pour quel raison on travaille avec une sous suite de b_n, pourqoui ne pas faire $d(b_n,a)\leq d(b_n,a_{n_k})+d(a_{n_k},a)$

Comment: C'est $d(b_{n_k},a_{n_k})$ qui tend vers $0$ (comme sous-suite de $d(b_n,a_n)$ qui tend vers $0$). Que pouvez-vous dire de $d(b_n,a_{n_k})$ ? Il y a deux indices indépendants $n$ et $n_k$ (Peut-\ etre serait-il plus clair d'appeler la sous-suite $a_{m_k}$ au lieu de $a_{n_k}$ (qui est une notation traditionnelle) ?

Comment: c'est juste que je ne sais pas comment introduire la sous suite b_{n_k}

Comment: On a extrait une sous-suite de la suite $a_n$. Cela veut dire simplement que l'on restreint l'ensemble des indices a un ensemble infini $E$. On range les éléments de $E$ en une suite $m_k$ d'entiers strictement croissante et on a $a_{m_k}$. On considère alors la sous-suite de la suite $b_n$ correspondant au meme ensemble $E$, c'est la suite $b_{m_k}$.

Comment: donc il faut se dire que si $d(a_n,b_n)\rightarrow 0$ alors $d(b_{n_k},a_{n_k})\rightarrow 0 $

Comment: Oui, c'est simplement que $d(b_{n_k},a_{n_k})$ est une sous-suite de la suite $d(b_n,a_n)$, qui converge vers $0$, donc cette sous-suite converge vers $0$ également.

Comment: merci, encor une question lorsque $d(A,B)=0$ on a directement l'existence des suite (a_n), (b_n) on a pas besoin de le démontrer ?

Comment: On peut dire un mot: $d(A,B)$ est la borne inférieure des $d(a,b)$, $a\in A$, $b\in B$, si cette borne inférieure est nulle, on dit qu'il existe pour $n\geq 1$ un couple $(a_n,b_n)$ tq $d(a_n,b_n)<1/n$, car $1/n>$ la borne inférieure.

Comment: on utilise la propriété caractéristique de l'inf ?

Comment: Voila..Bonne redaction, bye.